# Stop user from X'ing out of modeless window without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a client that is using JSP (Java) and Javascript/JQuery for their pages.  I have a requirement for a particular modeless pop up page that states the user cannot X out of the window if there is text in the description textarea (they will need to use a cancel button or clear out the text).  That's part is easy and I have found a ton of ways to do it online.  The part I am having trouble with is:  **They do NOT want the error in an alert box, they want the error message simply displayed in the same window without having to click and close the alert.**  I cannot seem to find anything that will disable the X button without the alert box.  Also, we're browser agnostic, so the solution must work for any browser.

If this alert is enforced by the browser and there's no way around it, I can obviously explain that to the client, but I am not sure if that's the case or not.

So, I am asking ether for some ideas on how to meet the requirement or if the requirement is impossible, some evidence to back that up.

This is what I've tried so far but gives the alert box, so it does not satisfactorily meet the requirement:

```js
function isDescriptionPopulated() {
    var desc = $("#description")
        .val();
    if (desc === "") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
    if (isDescriptionPopulated()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = undefined;
    }
});
```

I am far from a Javascript expert, so I'm hoping maybe one of you can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: It would be a huge security risk if you could prevent users from closing their window. Imagine how easy it would be for hackers to not allow closing a window would be unless you give them all your credid card information.

Comment: How about making a modal pop-up using CSS within the same window, instead of opening a separate window? Then you can do whatever you like with it.

Comment: Pet peeve: if you are returning a Boolean as a result of an if condition, just return the condition (perhaps negated depending on need). For instance `isDescriptionPopulated()` can end with `return desc !== "";` or better yet `return !!desc;` which returns true only if `desc` is a string with content (not null, not undefined, not "").

Comment: cloned: I see your point about the security.  In my case the user can leave via a button but the browser would know that.

Comment: ADyson: Understood, I asked my question based on the requirement supplied to me.  I will need to ask if other options are possible.